# iOS TablewView not showing data (delegates called)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates

I'm very new to iOS programming and just tried to setup a tab view, inckuding a normal one and a table view.

Now there is the problem, that the table view won't get updated. All cells are always empty.

This is how I declared my ViewController:

```
@interface SecondViewController : UITableViewController {
```

According to my logs all delegates are called correctly and even my Logs in this method are printed to the console.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CooperCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"CooperCell"];
    }

    NSLog(@"test");

    cell.textLabel.text = @"test";    
    return cell;
}
```

"test" is logges 3 times as my array has the size 3. So I don't get why it won't show. And of course I gave the cells the identifier "CooperCell" via the storyboard. Did I miss something else to link?

My SecondViewController.h looks like this:

```
@interface SecondViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
    NSMutableArray *eventArray;
}

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *eventArray;

- (void) fetchRecords;

@end
```

I was working with this tutorial: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-core-data/

Maybe i just really messed something up with the storyboard?

I created a new Tab controlled project. Then I deleted the second view controller and placed a TableViewController instead and continued with my SecondViewController.h and .m files

Comment: I used Basic. Before it was custom

Comment: What does that mean? :X

Comment: you many not setting delegate or datasource

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if you have connected your table view from storyboard to the IBOutlet variable UITablveView in your .h file.  You mentioned you have linked the cell.  Not sure that is the right thing to do.

Other possibility is that you have not identified your view controller on the storyboard to your class name (SecondViewController).

If not working after trying/confirming these, then share your .h file too.  We will be able to help more.

[image]

Comment: I edited question with .h file and referring tutorial. When i tried the tutorial standalone its working fine. And all they do is the same like mine.. just let my class inherit from TableViewController

Comment: And how can i set an identifier for my controller? I already was looking for some kind of thing.

Comment: See the image I added.  When you click on the SecondViewController in your storyboard, on the properties panel you should select your class i.e. SecondViewController.  Not the default UITableViewController.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look whether reloadData is being called to refresh table's content

Comment: Yes it is. Otherwise my Logs wouldn't be called

Answer (score 0):

As you created the second view controller(SecondViewController) as the UITableViewController, you don't need to set the table view datasource or delegate separately. The UITableViewController comes with a default table view and with a custom TableView cell. So, I don't think, you are missing any link to tableview datasource.

[image]

Let's do some troubleshoot.

(P.S: this is just what I would do. The following are not according to any standard. It is just based on my experience.)

*Test 1:*

You said, you used Basic. Try changing that back to custom Table view style. 
Now change the cell type to UITableViewCellStyleDefault in your cellForRowAtIndexPath method too.

Something like-

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CooperCell"];
}
```

Try building your code now.

*Test 2:*

Check if you have connected the second view controller to the tab bar item in the storyboard.

Try building your code now.

*Test 3:*

Lastly, in the storyboard, check if you have set the custom class as the SecondViewController or not. I think someone already posted a picture for that

Try building your code now.